# Are all apps on Google Play compatible with the Samsung Galaxy S4?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-4, compatibility

I wanted to know whether the *Samsung Galaxy S4* will run every app from the play store or not? I had done a lot of googling but failed to find an answer.

Answer (score 8):

In general, NO.

Some apps:

- run on specific devices only (i.e. not compatible with S4)
- run on specific Android versions
- available only in specific countries
- available only on specific carriers
- requires root access. (i.e. if phone is not rooted, it won't work)

Comment: You forgot to mention "are not available on specific carriers."

Comment: Or "are only available on specific carriers".

Comment: @Chahk an Al Thanks for that. Added into answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

No there are not all compatible. When you watching an application on Google play ( from your device ) if you cannot find the button for installing that app, that means that your device is not supported by that application. Also if you visit that application page on Google play desktop site, and your device is listed in your account than a message will appear in browser that says that specific application is not compatible with your device.

Answer (score -1):

I would say 80% app is compatible. And other 20% are for other specific devices. Specific android version and  specific screen size

Comment: What are you basing that on?  I've not seen any breakdowns like that of app/device compatibility, anywhere.

Comment: I'm with @Logos here. If you're going to give numbers, please cite your sources.